# Modify text displayed in simple_form input when using enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, enums, simple-form

I'm using simple_form for managing my users. For selecting the user role I use input as: :radio_button.

The collection come from a enum on the user model. How can I modify the text to show something specific like "Super Admin" instead of super_admin?

#### _form.html.slim

```
= form.input :role, collection: User.roles, as: :radio_buttons, item_wrapper_class: 'btn btn-default', checked: User.roles[user.role], required: true
```

#### user.rb

```
  enum role: [:super_admin, :admin, :generic]
```

Comment: Try to change the i18n file in config/locales like what it says to do in the [readme file](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n). Scroll down a little where it is stating how it supports options in collection helpers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the `label_method` option with the collection

```
= form.input :role, collection: User.roles, label_method: lambda {|k| k.humanize}, as: :radio_buttons, item_wrapper_class: 'btn btn-default', checked: User.roles[user.role], required: true
```

Comment: After thinking about it, using humanize in label_method might be the best answer. Just remember OP wanted the word admin in super_admin to be "Admin" with a capital A. Humanize only capitalizes the first word. Use `titleize` so they can use `lambda { |k| k.humanize.titleize }`

Comment: That works except the lamba needed to modified to `lambda { |k| k.first.humanize.titleize }`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do something more complex than calling a method on the key, Simple Form [has support](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#i18n) for translating collection options with I18n - you just have to provide the collection as an array of symbols for the lookup to work.

Here's what worked for me on SimpleForm 3.5.0:

Locale file:

```
en:
  simple_form:
    options:
      user:
        role:
          super_admin: 'Super Admin'
          admin: 'Admin'
          generic: 'Regular Joe'
```

View:

```
<%= f.input :role, collection: User.roles.symbolize_keys.keys %>
```

Comment: Ok, this is the correct way. Thanks @Jared !